# Why does deploying a .NET Compact Framework assembly cause .NET Desktop Framework assemblies to be deployed?

Tags: .net, deployment, compact-framework

I am trying to get one of my developers set up to work on a fairly large .NETCF project.  When we try to simply deploy the solution and all of its projects to a target device, deploying one of the projects triggers several assemblies from the desktop framework to be copied from the GAC to the device.  What on earth could cause this?  The assemblies from the "big" framework are ones like System.DirectoryServices, System.Design, and a bunch of others.

Answer (score 1):

What causes it is ennoneously adding a reference to a desktop assembly (either directly or by referencing another component that does).  Make certain that all of your references (including mscorlib, etc) are pointing to CF assemblies.

Comment: hmm... is there a reason why other dev stations don't pull in desktop assemblies when they deploy the solution?

One of the build messages on the affected workstation was that the compiler detected a conflict between 2 referenced assemblies (same versions, different public key tokens).  I believe the assembly in question was System.Web.Services.

Comment: And my bet is that if you look at those tokens, one is the desktop version.  Since there is a conflict, Studio is just picking one, and on that machine, it's picking the desktop version and running with it.